# Restarting an if statement or method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am implementing an a UITableView and have the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method implemented and within that method I have if loops (below):

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (self.someDetailViewController == nil) {
    if (row==0) {
        OneTableViewController *aDetail = [[OneTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OneDetail" bundle:nil];
        self.oneDetailViewController = aDetail;
        [aDetail release];
    } else if (row==1) {
        OneTableViewController *aDetail = [[OneTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwoDetail" bundle:nil];
        self.oneDetailViewController = aDetail;
        [aDetail release];
    }
}
```

However each time I select something in my table view (let's say row 0) I am taken to the secondary view (OneDetail) and then when I go back and select another row (row 1) and I expect to go to the other view (TwoDetail) **however** I am taken to OneDetail (to original row that was selected first) - how can this be when the user taps another row they are taken to the first row's secondary view that was originally tapped. This also happens vice versa (i.e. selecting row 1 and being taken to TwoDetail and then going back and selecting row 0 and also being taken to TwoDetail **not** OneDetail...

I was wondering if anyone knew how to 'restart' an if loop when the user presses the back button or how to overcome my issue in some other fashion. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Those if statements are not loops, they are conditional branches and only one branch executes each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the second time you enter the method, this check is returning false:

`if (self.someDetailViewController == nil)`

Thus, you never get into the part where you check which row you're on, and you're permanently stuck with whichever one you set first.

Comment: You'd correct it by setting `self.someDetailViewController = nil` sometime before the user can select another row in the table. Or you'd correct it by removing that check altogether, as it seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a loop.

You store your detail view controller in the instance variable `oneDetailViewController`.

Only if that `someDetailViewController` is nil, which is the case most probably only when the method is executed for the first time, you will assign a value.

A view controller that is initialized with "oneDetail".

Unfortunately you do not show the remaining code to us. I assume that you do not have a statement

```
self.someDetailViewController = nil;
```

further down in the method.

Why do yo do that == nil thing anyway? What is the detail view controller good for in the further processing? Just release it at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and create a new one next time it is executed. There is no need for an instance variable saving it.

Hoever, if you have good reasons for this unusual piece of code, which you did not share with us, then we could certainly make a suggestion on how to achieve that - if you let us know :)